# How can I access or check validation of the child component's template driven form in the super parent's component

Tags: angular, viewchild

Say i am having a set of components with the parent-child relationship. The 
    the structure is as follows:
    **[A]-->[B]-->[C]-->[D]**
     (i.e) A is the parent of B , 
     B is the parent of C ,
     C is the parent of D. 
    I need to check the validity of template-driven form in component **D** from 
    the component **A**. 
    I have tried using @viewchild(). 
    in my **componentA.html**

```html
<form #mainform ="ngform">
        <button
        [disabled]= "componentB?.ComponentC?.ComponentD?.form?.invalid">
        </button>
        </form>
```

This approach is not working.

How can I achieve this from A to D without using event emitter?

Answer (score -1):

It does not matter how deeply it is nested in the component tree. It matters how it is nested in the form tree.

Asumming the child controls are named `child`, `grandchild` and `grandgrandchild` you can do something like this:

```
<form #mainform="ngform">
  <button [disabled]="mainform.control.get('child.grandchild.grandgrandchild').invalid">
    </button>
</form>
```

We use the `mainform.control` to get the access to the underlying `FormGroup`. Now we have an access to all methods on the `FormGroup` class. You can see the full list [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup).

Next we use the [`get`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) method to traverse the form tree and reach for the child control.

If you have a form tree like this:

```
mainform: {
  child: {
    grandchild: {
       grandChild
    }
  }
}
```

Where `mainform`, `child`, and `grandchild` are `FromGroups` and `grandgrandchild is a`FormControl`.

You can access the `grandgrandchild` by typing: `mainForm.get('child.grandchild.grandchild')`

Comment: Can you please explain with an example on how to achieve it because I have not used nested forms @tomhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/5594389/tomasz-kula

Comment: @suriyaprakash check out my edit. Also please consider upvoting and accepting my answer :)